# Filling array with pointers to custom class. C++

Tags: c++, class

Consider the code below. Here I try to create an array that is suppost to take in pointers to objects of type Person. I wanted it's size to be 3 so i put a 3 inside the [ ]. However this 3 seem to do nothing. So i'm wondering what is the correct way of declaring the array? As you can see from the line below i can put the address to a person in 23 position of the array. Which I think is a bit weird since the memory is not reserved.

```
#include <iostream>
class Person {
    //some code
};

int main() {
    Person person1;

    Person* array_of_person[3];
    array_of_person[22] = &person1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << array_of_person[i] << "hey im out of bounds " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However this 3 seem to do nothing.

The `3` means: You declared an array of size 3.

The rest of your code is undefined behaviour for accessing this array out-of-bounds. I presume you expected to get some error or something. This is not how C++ works. If you do something wrong, wrong things will happen. When your code has undefined behaviour the compiler is not mandated to issue an error. As the name suggests it is undefined what your code does.

If you want some feedback use a `vector` and its `at` method, as in:

```
#include <iostream>
class Person {
    //some code
};

int main() {
    Person person1;
    std::vector<Person> array_of_person(3);

    array_of_person.at(22) = person1;  // out-of-bounds exception
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << array_of_person.at(i) << "hey im out of bounds " << std::endl; 
        // more out-of-bounds exceptions starting from index 3
    }
}
```

Its not clear why you used pointers, dont do it when not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The array is declared correctly.
Out of bounds access is not always detected by C++, especially if there is nothing else after the array. If you had some other variables declared after it, they probably would be trashed. Memory is allocated by pages, which typically are 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't do runtime checking on array bounds. That's up to you. (And it's also why there are array classes in the standard library.)

So you're free to stuff something into array_of_persons[22], but you're stepping on random memory somewhere. You have no idea what you stepped on, but nothing is going to stop you.

But you changed the value of some random data.

Comment: this is misleading. OPs code can be considered  equivalent to `int main(){}` by a compiler. Not necessarily any value is changed

Comment: The OP's code is a minimalized sample. We don't know that it would normally be main() where this is happening. And the std::cout is still there.

Comment: IMHO, @formerlyknownas_463035818 is simply reiterating that when UB exists, ANYTHING can happen.  And ANYTHING can include behaving as if the main was null-body.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the memory is not reserved, but it still exists. Those c style arrays don't have bound checks (like python or other languages).

You need to be carefulle what you access.
Arrays are like pointers in C++.
`array_of_person[22]` is the same as `*(array_of_person+22)`
Its the pointer to the 0th value of `array_of_person[]` and skips 22 elements ahead.

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments: the memory is not guaranteed to exist or what data there is. You are most likely either gonna segfault or corrupt some data. C++ doesn't guarantee anything here except for which Address you are trying to access.

Comment: In the C++ sense, it doesn't exist. Or rather, it's not guaranteed to exist--even if the hardware will accept that as a memory address, no memory exists there. You should never try and do something like this because it is undefined behavior.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to exist; you will get runtime error only if the array straddles the allocated page boundaries. Otherwise, some other data will be trashed.

Comment: Well, yes. Accessing out of bound Memory is undefined behavior. I didn't say you should do it. But the general idiom of how pointer arithmetic works is still true. What is inside that memory o r if it even exists c++ can not guarantee. What Address you are trying to access though is pretty clear.

Comment: unless you specify the compiler version and all options used and the target architecture it is meaningless to speculate what happens in the presence of UB. C++ is written against an abstract machine where no memory exists beyond the bounds of an array

Comment: "general idiom of how pointer arithmetic works is still true" - IMHO, when UB exists, ANYTHING can happen. Anything includes the generation of invalid pointer arithmetic.  What actually happens can NOT be usefully speculated about.  What happens with the next compiler version can NOT be usefully speculated about.  etc.